# Track Laravel routes quickly

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with a big, messy Laravel Project in which routes file (web.php, api.php) include  thousands of nested routes. Finding which controller@function responds to the url is time consuming and error-prone. Is there any elegant method for that?

for example convert "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" to QuestionContrller@newQuestion.

Comment: you can use some of the flags and filtering ability that `route:list` provides `php artisan help route:list`, to help a bit ... otherwise you could get the route collection from the router, create a request instance with the path and method you want and ask the collection to match it, then you can pull the 'action' from the route that it finds

Comment: Thanks for your advise. That's much better than manual lookups. Combined with grep / findstr,  I can convert url to function much faster. The drawback is that I have remove variable parts manually.

Comment: otherwise try the code i have in the answer and adjust it to your needs, even your own command to find a route and its action ; if you know the URI you would be accessing it will find the route

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are other ways to go about that, but you can get the route collection of all the routes and attempt to have it match a request to a route:

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::create('questions/ask');

try {
    $route = Route::getRoutes()->match($request);
    $action = $route->getAction('uses');
    dump($action):
} catch (...) { 
    // couldn't match a route
}
```

If you needed to use a different method other than `GET`, that would be the second argument to `Request::create`.

Answer (score 0):

I normally find my associated Controller method to a route by executing this command in my terminal:

`php artisan route:list | grep my/url/which/im/looking/for`

[image]

Or if you want to be more specific you can write more specific REGEX in grep:

`php artisan route:list | grep POST.*my/url/which/im/looking/for`

[image]